# Enabling older Android SDK's?

Tags: android, sdk, version

I'm trying to figure out how to enable older Android Platforms (the phone I have to test on is API Level 10 but I'm using API Level 13).

Now, the only build target Eclipse knows about is 3.2 (API Level 13). When I launch the "Android SDK and AVD Manager" and click on available packages it doesn't show any older versions (and I do NOT have "Display updates only" checked).

How do you enable older SDK versions with Android?

Comment: Are the other API levels displayed in your AVD Manager?

Comment: Nope. "Android Repository" only has 2 things under it: "Android SDK Tools, revision 14" and "Adnroid SDK Platform-tools, revision 8"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update to the R14 tools. There is no "Android SDK and AVD Manager" any more -- those are broken out into two separate windows. For reasons I have not fully understood, they switched the SDK repositories to a new format which is incompatible with the older tools.

Comment: Agreed :)
Update your Android tools to the latest version (which you can do from the SDK manager) and try again.